# Adding border to Cardview which contains an ImageView

Tags: android, background, imageview, cardview

I would like to add a border to a cardview which contains an ImageView. It works perfect if I use an icon as a image (a vector graphic). The image is inside an ImageView with the size MATCH_PARENT and added to a cardview. The cardview should be responsible for the border. Therefore I set the background image of the cardview this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#fff"/>
<stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#e6e6e6" />
<corners android:radius="20dp"/>
<padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

So the image of the ImageView seems to overwrite the background of the cardview. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct solution to using a drawable, but I'd suggest to use [`MaterialCardView`](https://material.io/components/cards/android) which offers you the same specs as in your drawable using `app:strokeColor`, `app:strokeWidth` & `app:cardCornerRadius`:

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:strokeColor="#e6e6e6"
    app:strokeWidth="1dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_image" />
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Note: the margin added to the `ImageView` that equals to the card stroke so that it's not covered by the card stroke, you can remove it if you'd like to.